# Select all Same jtable value in one click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I am creating a prototype of a payroll for my project, i would like to ask, How can i select all value with the same name and Employee's id in table with just clicking one of them? And all the selected row will pass to another table.  Please help me, I just don't have no idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i select all value with the same name and Employee's id

First of all I would suggest that it is the Employee's Id that is unique, so you would want to search the table for the selected id.

Easiest approach would be to "filter" the table based on the Employee's Id. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). The working example shows how to do a dynamic search as you type text into a text field.

> And all the selected row will pass to another table

Now you have all the filtered data in the table to you just iterate through the `JTable` using the `getValueAt(...)` method to get the data you want and that add the data to another `JTable` using the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` of that table.